# How many positive integers smaller than $1000$ and non-divisible by either $2$, $3$ or $5$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I thought about calculating the ones that **are** divisible and then subtracting, but don't know if that's the best way to go here.

We can calculate that there are $499$ integers divisible by $2$ and smaller than $1000$. Also, $333$ divisible by $3$ and $199$ divisible by $5$. But then we'd have to calculate the ones divisible by $2$ AND $3$, $2$ AND $5$, $3$ AND $5$, all three and so on. Is there a faster way for this?

Comment: Basically, no. It's a simple application of [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Isn't it fast enough? Notice there is nothing in your *"and so on"*: after you have all three, you are done.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut - I see, thank you. Of course the "and so on" was my bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$999-\lfloor\frac{999}{2}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{999}{3}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{999}{5}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{999}{2\times3}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{999}{2\times5}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{999}{3\times5}\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{999}{2\times3\times5}\rfloor=266$

Comment: @Straightfw: You're welcome :)